# Applying FA (factor analysis) to groupings

Tags: r

Let's say X is a dataframe with numerical columns except one `salaryRange` column, and I want to do FA analysis for each group of `salaryRange` that has more than 100 observations. I managed to do this, but can't seem to nail it (the filtering of more than 100 observations I couldn't do):

```
X %>%
  group_by(salaryRange) %>%
  summarise(factanal(factors = 3 scores = "Bartlett")) -> Y
```

The function factanal without grouping works like this:

```
s <- factanal(X[2:6],factors = 2, scores = "Bartlett") # only numerical columns as input
```

Ideally I would end up with all FA solution for all salaryRanges, but maybe FA is not a function suitable for `summarise()`. Any help welcome!

Here the dataset for reproducing purposes:

```
v1 <- c('high','low','medium','medium','medium','high','medium','medium','high','medium','high','low','high','medium','low','medium','low','high','high','high','high','medium')
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5,5,4,3,2)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6,2,4,3,1)
v4 <- c(3,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,6,4,1,4,2,4)
v5 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,4,5,1,1,1,1)
v6 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,6,5,4,2,3,1,2)
v7 <- c(1,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,3,1,2,2,1,1,6,5,4,2,3,1,2)
v8 <- c(2,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,4,2,3,1,2)
X <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)
colnames(X) <- c('salaryRange', 'VAR1', 'VAR2','VAR3','VAR4','VAR5')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the data.frame.

Comment: Good point :) I have updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, this does not require for the same shared but it should work on your original data if you have enough rows.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- X %>%
  group_by(salaryRange) %>%
  summarise(out = list(factanal(cur_data(),factors = 2, scores = "Bartlett")))
```

You can access the output for each `salaryRange` using `result$out`.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. As a newbie I have seen the group_by always before the result output. I added some more random rows and got this error ´Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `out`.
ℹ `out = list(factanal(cur_data(), factors = 2, scores = "Bartlett"))`.
x Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[8,8] = 0
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: salaryRange = high.´

Comment: EDIT: I tried with another dataset, and it worked. THANK YOU!